# How to collect the values from a certain bin in plt.hist command?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to collect the number of values from a certain bin. Documentation says clearly that if bins is
a sequence [1, 2, 3, 4], then first bin is [1,2) where 2 is excluded and second bin is [2,3) and last
would be [3,4].
But in my code i take bins as an integer, then according to documentation it defines the number of
equal-width bins in the range. Suppose in this case if print bin edges I get,

```
`[1,3,5,7]`
```

My question the fist bin edge would be [1,3) or [1,3]. Should I include 3 or exclude it?

Comment: Due to floating point rounding errors, it is hard to know beforehand in which bin a value on a boundary will fall. If you want to work with integers, it's recommended to have your bin boundaries on halves.

Comment: I mean if I assign bins=integer value suppose 4 then and suppose I print binedges and they appear as [1,3,5,7]. I want to collect all values residing in first bin. So what will be the boundary of first bin [1,3] or [1,3). Should I include 3 in the boundary of first bin or not?

Comment: If you set bins=4, the boundaries would be `[1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 7.0]`.  Why don't you run a few tests to see what happens? Something like `values, bounds, _ = plt.hist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], bins=3)`? But please note it's recommended to have your bin boundaries on halves. For example, `bins=np.arange(0.5, 9, 2)`. There are no guarantees about what happens exactly on the bin boundaries.